# Create and get magento sessions from a decoupled frontend

Tags: php, magento, session

We are planning to use ReactJs for the front-end in magento and have it completely decoupled from it so that we do not have specify it in templates and other configuration files.

We intend to use Magento only for the back end purpose.

Now, for that matter, how ,when and which of the sessions are to be initialized? I do not seem to find exact life cycle and sequence of events to initialized these sessions.

When and which of the sessions are to be initialized?

Comment: I think you shall try with `core/session`

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo: Any example? I do not really know magento

Comment: How are you planning to render react js? Are you going to use node server for it?

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo: That's correct